# In databricks using python, dbutils.fs.mount gives java.lang.NullPointerException: authEndpoint trying to mount using abfss. wasbs works fine

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

When using db.fs.mount in databricks to connect to azure gen2 data lake a authEndpoint error is received when attempting to connect to "abfss://theDir@theDataLake.blob.core.windows.net/" HOWEVER, connecting to "wasbs://theDir@theDataLake.blob.core.windows.net/" works fine.  I am trying to understand why abfss causes the authEndpoint error while wasbs does not.

```
enter code here
#fails
endpoint = "abfss://theDir@theDataLake.blob.core.windows.net/";
dbutils.fs.mount(
   source = endpoint,
   mount_point = "/mnt/test",
   extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.theDataLake.blob.core.windows.net" : "xxxxxx"})

#works
endpoint = "wasbs://theDir@theDataLake.blob.core.windows.net/";
dbutils.fs.mount(
   source = endpoint,
   mount_point = "/mnt/test",
   extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.theDataLake.blob.core.windows.net" : "xxxxxx"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mount the ABFSS protocol using the storage key.  You can mount with ABFSS only when using Service Principal ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#---mount-adls-gen2-storage)), and it requires another set of parameters for `extra_configs`:

```
{"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
"fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<application-id>",
"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope-name>",key="<service-credential-key-name>"),
"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token"}
```